# How to read txt file with utf-8 characters in C++?

Tags: c++, ifstream

I need to read from a file with utf-8 characters.

I tried to use `std::wifstream` but I only get blank lines in the output.
I also find this solution `file.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::empty(), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>));` but empty() can`t be found, and as I read this is a rather outdated way.

Is there any modern way to solve my problem?

Comment: wide characters aren't supposed to be used for UTF-8

Comment: @phuclv What should I use?

Comment: `std::ifstream` after setting the locale to UTF-8 if necessary

Comment: @pluclv Ok, it works, but then how can I get a UTF-8 character from `std::string` ?

Comment: I need to build a trie where each node has a letter.